# for loop over specific files in a directory using Bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

In a directory you have some various files - `.txt`, `.sh` and then plan files without a `.foo` modifier.

If you `ls` the directory:

```
blah.txt
blah.sh
blah
blahs
```

How do I tell a for-loop to only use files without a `.foo` modify? So "do stuff" on files blah and blahs in the above example.

The basic syntax is:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/home/shep/Desktop/test/*

for f in $FILES
do
    XYZ functions
done
```

As you can see this effectively loops over everything in the directory. How can I exclude the `.sh`, `.txt` or any other modifier?

I have been playing with some if statements but I am really curious if I can select for those non modified files.

Also could someone tell me the proper jargon for these plain text files without .txt?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/home/shep/Desktop/test/*

for f in $FILES
do
if [[ "$f" != *\.* ]]
then
  DO STUFF
fi
done
```

Comment: This works for me in a modified form. Some of my file names contain ".'s" so using *\.* can still select them. What is fi used for n your code?   Thank you!

Comment: It's just the endif for bash (if backwards).

Comment: hmm that would be why 'done' threw an error, needed to close the if statement. Cool thanks.

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you added an explanation as to why this is a solution to OP's question.

Answer (score 14):

If you want it a little bit more complex, you can use the find-command.

For the current directory:

```
for i in `find . -type f -regex \.\\/[A-Za-z0-9]*`
do
WHAT U WANT DONE
done
```

explanation:

```
find . -> starts find in the current dir
-type f -> find only files
-regex -> use a regular expression
\.\\/[A-Za-z0-9]* -> thats the expression, this matches all files which starts with ./
(because we start in the current dir all files starts with this) and has only chars
and numbers in the filename.
```

http://infofreund.de/bash-loop-through-files/

Answer (score 3):

You can use negative wildcards? to filter them out:

```
$ ls -1
a.txt
b.txt
c.png
d.py
$ ls -1 !(*.txt)
c.png
d.py
$ ls -1 !(*.txt|*.py)
c.png
```

Comment: Ok, but say I have a directory with more than two of them. Is there a logical way to make bash do this for me? So that it can be applied on most directories while working the same way.

Comment: @jon_shep: More than two of what?

Comment: file extensions. In your example you had to manually exclude them.

Comment: `!(*.*)`, and no, this is not POSIX.

Comment: You also need to set the `extglob` option for this to work: `shopt -s extglob`.