# Change first line recursively in all php files using bash

Tags: php, bash

I have a WordPress site and want to change first line of all php files recursively using bash. How should I do? I am not very familiar with bash.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Loop through files (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823830/bash-for-loop-over-specific-files-in-a-directory) and make your change...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change first line to some other line:

```
sed -i '1s/.*/changed line/' *.php
```

Adding a line before first line:

```
sed -i '1s/^/changed line\n/' *.php
```

Comment: While it worked, it also modified all the line endings in my files. In vim I see ^M at the end.

Answer (score 3):

In order to modify the first line of the file, you can use this :

```
awk 'NR==1 {$0="what you want"} 1' *.php
```

You'll find more info here : [bash: replace an entire line in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145270/bash-replace-an-entire-line-in-a-text-file)

Then to do it recursively, you can use a `find` first and then execute the awk command on every found file.

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec awk 'NR==1 {$0="what you want"} 1'
```

More info about the `find` command here : https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Scope

Comment: There is a slight catch here. `awk` writes the o/p to stdout, not back to file.

Comment: I used both of the responds and executed the following: find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '1 s/.*/<?php/' '{}' \;

Answer (score 2):

I used both above answers and executed the following:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '1 s/.*/<?php/' '{}' \;
```

So thanks both of you Theox and anishsane for your help