Retrieving .pha files from RXTE for XSPEC analysis
I downloaded a file from the HEASARC browse feature from RXTE and I am trying to put it through XSPEC table models, but they require an OGIP .pha file and the data I download saves as a directory  with many subdirectories.
I tried to use the ftascii2pha command that comes with xspec ftools but it does not work as my data is a directory and not a file. I'm really not sure how to fix this without going into each file in each sub-directory and plugging all of them into the command one at a time which seems inefficient and like their must be a better solution (especially as I've read papers with much larger datasets seemingly also collected from the same place using the same tools.) Would really appreciate any and all advice you have!

Maybe you could write a "shell script" to run the program on each file for you?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/14823830/1358308 looks relevant
